# Searching for a phrase in a document

Tags: python

Task is to match a keyword from a paragraph, what I did was I broke the paragraph into words and put them in a list and then used the search words from another list and did a match.

data :

```
Automatic Product Title Tagging
Aim: To automate the process of product title tagging using manually tagged data. 

ROUTE OPTIMIZATION – Spring Clean
Aim:  Minimizing the overall travel time using optimization techniques. 

CUSTOMER SEGMENTATION:
Aim:  Develop an engine which segments and provides the score for
      customers based on their behavior and analyze their purchasing pattern.
```

Attempted code:

```
s = ['tagged', 'product title',  'tagging', 'analyze']

skills = []
for word in data.split():

    print(word)    
    word.lower()
    if word in s:

        skills.append(word)
skills1 = list(set(skills))

print(skills1)

['tagged', 'tagging', 'analyze']
```

As I used the split function, every word is split and hence I am not able to detect the word `product title` which is there in the paragraph.

Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Comment: why did you use `split`?

Comment: in the first go, i thought ill split the data into words and then search it, but here I want a word product title which has a space between, and I couldnt find a way to solve it. @Ev.Kounis

Comment: you do not have to have a `list` to check membership. You can do that with strings as well. In fact, in your case, it would remove the problem you are taking about.

Comment: `'product title'` is not a word. So you are not only looking for words. Therefore, it is not appropriate to split your input into words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the list `s` and check if element in string.

**Demo:**

```
data = """
 Automatic Product Title Tagging  
 Aim: To automate the process of product title tagging using manually tagged data.
 ROUTE OPTIMIZATION – Spring Clean
 Aim:  Minimizing the overall travel time using optimization techniques.
 CUSTOMER SEGMENTATION:
 Aim:  Develop an engine which segments and provides the score for  
       customers based on their behavior and analyze their purchasing
       pattern. 
"""
s = ['tagged', 'product title',  'tagging', 'analyze']
data = data.lower()

skills = []
for i in s:
    if i.lower() in data:
        skills.append(i)
print(skills)
```

Or in a single line.

```
skills = [i for i in s if i.lower() in data]
```

**Output:**

```
['tagged', 'product title', 'tagging', 'analyze']
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not appreciated here. Please explain how your proposed solution solves the problem and a little on the details of how you implemented.

Comment: If you don't care about the order or repetitions of words, you can achieve the same thing using `skills = list(set(s) & set(data))` in a slightly more readable manner.

Comment: The `sub is in data` expression will not respect word boundaries, so it might catch something like `untagged`, `analyzers` or `byproduct titles` in the text - NOT what was intended.

Comment: @LeoK. That's a valid case. I did not think of that.

Answer (score 3):

What you are searching for is not a 'keyword' but a phrase. One solution is to use a regular expression search (a simple `substring is in text` construct won't work well because when given 'product title', it might catch `byproduct titles`, which isn't what you want).

This should do it:

```
import re
[ k for k in skills if re.search( r'\b' + k + r'\b', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE ) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

split() splits the string around the passed argument. The default argument for split() is a space. Since you want to search 'product title' which also includes a space, you can do one of these:

1) Search for the phrase directly in the paragraph

2) if you split, then you can search for a match in i and i+1 indices

Comment: This would be a pain to generalise to n-word phrases, but it would probably work for the current example.

Comment: yes, for n-word phrase the first approach would be better

Comment: "The default argument for split() is a space" => nope, it's "all whitespace characters" - example : `"a\nb\tc".split()` => `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 0):

"Aim:" must be in each line of "data"
so I'll find the index for this word("Aim:")

```
p = "Automatic Product Title Tagging  Aim: To automate the process of product title tagging using manually tagged data."
index = p.find("Aim:") # 33
print(p[33:])
output:
"Aim: To automate the process of product title tagging using manually tagged data."
w_lenght = len("Aim:") # 4 : for exclude word "Aim:"
print(p[37:])
output:
" To automate the process of product title tagging using manually tagged data."
```

example:

```
s = ['tagged', 'product title',  'tagging', 'analyze']
skills = []
for line in data.split("\n"):
    index = line.find("Aim:") + len("Aim:") #4
    if index != -1:
    for word in line[index:].split():
        if word.lower() in s:
            skills.append(word)
            print(word)
```